# How to convert Bq/g to Sievert (Dose), and how to get values Sv/Bq?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, unit-conversion

- How to convert Bq/g (Activity) to Sievert/g(Dose)?
- How can I get values in (Sv/Bq)?

Please help, it is really confusing.

Comment: This can all be found in, for instance, the [appropriate wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert), but there is no universal conversion factor because it varies by the energy of the decay line, the radiation type of the decay line, *and* by the type of tissue exposed. You need to start by understanding what each of these units is (and isn't) and also what the units you are missing are (radiated energy, deposited energy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a stright forward convertion.
The $Bq$  it's 1 decay per second. We will consider $X$ activity in $[Bq]$. Depending on the decay, it will release some energy. So you first need the energy released per decay. Let's consider a convertion $1 [decay]=b[Joule]$. Then you will get that $bX$ it's the power in $[Joule/s]$.

After this you need to account how much time were you exposed to the source of the radiatión, let's say it's $t$ in $[s]$. $tbX$ it's the energy released.

After that, you need to see how much mass was irradiated. This is a tricky part, because maybe you want to consider your lung or your testicle or all your body. So let's consider that a mass $M$ was irradiated in $[kg]$. $tbX/M$ it's the energy per mass going through the tissue.

But maybe there is a shielding or not all energy released was absorbed. We will hide all this complexity behind a number $0<D<1$, the absorbed energy. Then the effective absorved energy it's $DtbX/M$. If it's hard to estimate this, you can say that $D=1$. This is something like being naked and all the radiation it's absorbed.

But not all radiation it's equally damaging and not all the tissues matter equally when absorbing radiation. This it's the Q number and it's $Q=1$ for $\gamma$ radiation and $Q=20$ for $\alpha$ radiation if you consider all your body being in danger. So the Dose it's $QRtbX/M$.

This it's considering a single kind of radiation ($Q$ factor) and that there is only one kind of decay. If you have multiple sources of radiation you have to add all the different doses.

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to include the distance to the emitting source in this calculation?